# How to call another function or create another thread after do_post finishing all responses in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, httpserver

In python3, I want something like：

```
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        self.finish
        call_a_function()/ create_a_thread() ...
```

Can this be possible in some way?